# Connection pool exhaustion: how to limit reactor's concurrent events

Tags: java, spring, reactor, project-reactor

My Spring v4 application uses Reactor v2's `reactor.bus.EventBus` extensively, including two `reactor.fm.Consumer`s which access Spring Data JPA. The database is limited to some number of connections, let's say 100, so I don't want anymore than, say, 75 events in the JPA `Consumer`s at any one time. To enforce this restriction, I'm adding `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` with a maximum thread pool size of 75 which should address the problem but it doesn't feel right -- it feels like I'm duplicating/overlapping-with Reactor's functionality (e.g. `reactor.core.Dispatcher`) -- is there a more Reactor-ish (v2) way to limit how many events are acted on concurrently?

Comment: What will you do with those events that are over this limit? If you want them to wait (and not drop them) they might just as well block on the database connection pool and wait for an available connection. If you need some portion of possible connections available for other parts of application, you can create two separate connection pools.

Comment: Events are FIFO queued, @JiriTousek, "indefinitely". In this case, queuing prior to transaction start is preferred to avoid transaction interleaving.